# How to re compile a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a directive to render a tree-like data.
As the data can be filtered.
When I clear the filter; I expect my directive respond to the new change in the data and update itself but it doesn't.
only when I change the view/route the directive get updated.

I tried to execute this code on clearing the filter event

```
$scope.$on('clearingStockFilter', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $compile($element.contents())($scope);
                },300);
            });
```

But I end with making cloned directive, so I start see the data twice in the View

Comment: If the directive is design properly, it does not need to be re-compiled when data changes. Also the $compile service adds watchers to scope each time it executes. This will cause memory leaks and duplication of watchers. Please show the code for the entire directive so that we can recommend a better approach.

Comment: georgeawg I agree the directive shouldn't need to be re-complied if the data changes; but I was using "angular-bindonce" as I am dealing with large amount of data; therefore I was trying to re-compile the directive on specific event.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg

Comment: If the code uses a router, re-loading the view will reset the [one-time bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) without memory leaks. If you write a directive that does the equivalent, that directive needs to address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the element back with the compiled one;

```
var newEl = $compile($element.contents())($scope);
$element.replaceWith(newEl);
```

Btw, that might not be the best way to achieve what you are trying to do.